# Flatten nested hashes in an array - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of nested hashes:

```
[{"Group"=>"PR",
  "Test1"=>{"Code"=>"100", " Price"=>"24.00", "AdditionalInfo"=>{"Cross"=>"true", "CrossId"=>"6"}},
  "Test2"=>{"Code"=>"277", " Price"=>"12.00", "AdditionalInfo"=>{"Cross"=>"false"}}},
 {"Group"=>"CO",
  "Test1"=>{"Code"=>"45", " Price"=>"20.00", "AdditionalInfo"=>{"Cross"=>"true", "CrossId"=>"1"}},
  "Test2"=>{"Code"=>"27", " Price"=>"15.00", "AdditionalInfo"=>{"Cross"=>"true", "CrossId"=>"2"}},
  "Test6"=>{"Code"=>"131", " Price"=>"7.00", "AdditionalInfo"=>{"Cross"=>"false"}}},
 {"Group"=>"OA",
  "Test1"=>{"Code"=>"136", " Price"=>"14.00", "AdditionalInfo"=>{"Cross"=>"true", "CrossId"=>"7"}},
  "Test2"=>{"Code"=>"18", " Price"=>"19.00", "AdditionalInfo"=>{"Cross"=>"true", "CrossId"=>"7"}},
  "Test3"=>{"Code"=>"50", " Price"=>"8.00", "AdditionalInfo"=>{"Cross"=>"false"}},
  "Test4"=>{"Code"=>"23", " Price"=>"3.00", "AdditionalInfo"=>{"Cross"=>"true", "CrossId"=>"8"}}}
]
```

I need to flatten the nested hash inside the array and put inside the same array like below.

```
[
  { "Group"=>"PR", "Code"=>"100", " Price"=>"24.00", "Cross"=>"true", "CrossId"=>"6" },
  { "Group"=>"PR", "Code"=>"277", " Price"=>"12.00", "Cross"=>"false" },
  { "Group"=>"CO", "Code"=>"45", " Price"=>"20.00", "Cross"=>"true", "CrossId"=>"1" },
  { "Group"=>"CO", "Code"=>"27", " Price"=>"15.00", "Cross"=>"true", "CrossId"=>"2" },
  { "Group"=>"CO", "Code"=>"131", " Price"=>"7.00", "Cross"=>"false" },
  { "Group"=>"OA", "Code"=>"136", " Price"=>"14.00", "Cross"=>"true", "CrossId"=>"7" },
  { "Group"=>"OA", "Code"=>"18", " Price"=>"19.00", "Cross"=>"true", "CrossId"=>"7" },
  { "Group"=>"OA", "Code"=>"50", " Price"=>"8.00", "Cross"=>"false" },
  { "Group"=>"OA", "Code"=>"23", " Price"=>"3.00", "Cross"=>"true", "CrossId"=>"8" }
]
```

Can anyone help!

Comment: Isn't this more like looping the hash and plucking only the required key values and appending in a new array and then finally setting the new array to the old one ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I need to flatten the nested hash inside the array […]" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Great!! Nice to see your feedback! Thank you. I will try your suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input.flat_map do |h|
  # split the input into group and tests in the first place
  h.partition { |k, v| k == "Group" }.reduce(&:product)
end.map do |(name, group), (_, data)|
  # due to product above each element is a 2×2 array
  # first item is the Group, the second is the TestN
  {name => group}.merge(data.merge(data.delete("AdditionalInfo")))
end
```

Comment: Excellent! Working perfectly!

Comment: How about `data.merge(data.delete("AdditionalInfo"))`? That feels more natural to me, and it makes each hash have the "correct" order of elements shown in the question.

Comment: @StefanPochmann indeed, updated, thanks. I always feel uncomfortable mutating objects and hesitate to refactor what works :)